# Windows Phone 8.1 device registration error code 0x64

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I wanted to get started with app development for windows phone 8.1. I own an up-to-date Lumia 630 device with Windows Phone 8.1 which I wanted to use as test device. Now, the problem is that i can't register this device as a test device. The registration tool which came with the sdk 8.1 always give me the 0x64 error code. I googled this problem but none of the solutions (including the ones here on stackoverflow) solved the problem for me. My phone has internet connection through wi-fi and is unlocked and up-to-date (tryed restarting and not using wi-fi). Also the windows background service is running (also tryed restarting it). An up-to-date windows 10 is running on the laptop with which I want to develop.

My microsoft account is not a developer account but from my understanding, i should still be able to use at least one device as test device without having to pay.

I also posted this question in the [microsoft forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/6f74b2c7-e700-40cd-880e-b7f145b51a30/windows-phone-developer-registration-81-shows-error-code-0x64?forum=wpsubmit).

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your account must be associated with dev account.

[image]

Comment: I saw this but the error doesn't state that this is the problem. And a developer account costs 14€. Shouldn't it be possible to develop an app before paying?

Comment: If you want to test with physical device then your phone must be developer unlock (that's what MS state) else Emulator will be only option. Other option is Dreamspark(if you are student).

Comment: Hi, I have a similar issue. I also have a developer account associated to a MS account but that does not help

Comment: I believe this is a more widespread issue. I came here also hoping for a solution, but it seems that this is a fairly recent bug affecting several developers. Hopefully this can get some official attention from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what changed, but it appears this is now fixed. I am able to register multiple devices to my developer account again.